# CSS: custom shaped div with double borders

Tags: css

I've got a challenge for you all. I'm trying to make the following shape without using any  [image: images:]

What's difficult about it (impossible?) for me is the double border. Sure, I could put some other shapes over the cutouts but then the border lines would be disrupted. Anyone got any ideas?

Comment: You can't really make custom shapes with pure css. Shapes such as triangles are basically hacks, so in order to make a complex shape like the one in that image, you're likely better off looking at alternatives such as SVG or using images

Comment: I'd say go SVG. You won't be able to get a double border like that w/ pseudo-elements.

Comment: @Jeff_Powers , yes it could :) http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/lqzcm

Comment: @GCyrillus By all that is holy, that use of box-shadow is pure awesome, +1!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I answered to something simular using box-shadow to draw borders and cut off background a couple of days ago.
Here , i come with something close to your drawing http://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/lqzcm

```
div {
  margin:3em;
  border:1px solid;
  box-shadow:inset 0 0 0 4px white,
    inset 0 0 0 5px black;
  min-height:10em;
  position:relative;
  background:pink;
}
div:before {
  content:'';
  display:inline-block;
  float:left;
  width:5%;
  height:2em;
  height:12vh;
  background:white;
  box-shadow: 
    -1px -1px white,
    2px 2px 0 2px white, 
    1px 4px 0 0 black,
    4px 5px 0 0 black,
    5px 4px 0 0 black,
    inset -1px -1px 0 0 black;
}
div:after {
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
  height:32px;
  width:32px;
  background:white;
  box-shadow:1px 1px 0 0 black,
    4px 4px 0 0 white,
    5px 5px 0 0 black;
  right:0;
  top:3em;
  margin-right:-18px;
  transform:rotate(135deg);
}
```

Comment: I'm impressed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

I believe that SVG is the way you should go. However, just to see if it was possible, I decided to make this shape using pure HTML and CSS.

Here's the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/n4wCw/2/).

### HTML

```
<div id="wrap">
    <div id="mainshape"></div>
    <div id="upperleftcut"></div>
    <div id="diamondcut"></div>
</div>
```

We will be using 3 shapes here, and they'll be positioned inside a wrapper that will act as the overall shape. The two cutaways are their own divs.

### CSS

```
#wrap {
    width: 206px;
    height: 150px;
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#upperleftcut, #mainshape, #diamondcut {
    position: absolute;
    background-color: white;
    border-style: double;
}

#upperleftcut {
    border-style: none double double none;
    width: 100px;
    height: 20px;
}

#diamondcut {
    -moz-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -o-transform:rotate(45deg);
    -ms-transform:rotate(45deg);
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    left: 197px;
    top: 50px;
    border-style: double;
}

#mainshape {
    border-style: double;
    background-color: white;
    width: 200px;
    height: 144px;
}
```

The CSS property you are looking for is `border-style: double;`. The divs have each been absolutely positioned within the wrapper, and the diamond one has been rotated to form the desired triangle cut.

### Conclusion

This would be far easier to do with an SVG, and far more flexible as well. The borders here between the different shapes also don't line up nicely. Don't do this with CSS, but know that you can.

As far as I can tell, *you can't get rid of those border overlaps.*